# why i am getting this error trying to get property of non-object?

Tags: codeigniter-2

i am trying to update this and shows  **Trying to get property of non-object** .how to solve this can anybody help me

```
  $data['dotdprod'] = $this->Product_model->get_products($data['dotdcat']->id, '5', '0', 'sort_price', 'ASC');
```

and model is:

```
function get_products($category_id = false, $limit = false, $offset = false, $by=false, $sort=false)
{
    //if we are provided a category_id, then get products according to category
    if ($category_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('category_products.*, products.*, LEAST(IFNULL(NULLIF(saleprice, 0), price), price) as sort_price', false)->from('category_products')->join('products', 'category_products.product_id=products.id')->where(array('category_id'=>$category_id, 'enabled'=>1));

        $this->db->order_by($by, $sort);

        $result = $this->db->limit($limit)->offset($offset)->get()->result();

        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        //sort by alphabetically by default
        $this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC');
        $result = $this->db->get('products');

        return $result->result();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There error is warning you that you are trying to access a property on something that doesn't have properties.

When you try to access `$data['dotdcat']->id`, this assumes that `$data['dotdcat']` is an object. If it isn't, then the error you see is thrown.

I'm not sure where the error is thrown, but anywhere you are using the arrow operator `->` - php assumes the left side of that operator is an object.